Is there a PowerShell way to retrieve the stats in the Outlook Connection Status window?
Is there a PowerShell way to retrieve the stats in the Outlook Connection Status window?  We want to monitor Red/Fail and Avg Resp in particular.  Thanks in advance.
I have Googled around and all that I have found is this:
$Outlook = new-object -com outlook.application 
$Namespace = $Outlook.getNamespace("MAPI")

